Is there a better way to retrieve frontend users from a database in vue.js
So I have my javascript code below which is essentially for a social media and upon clicking a certain button it goes to the next user page, my question is is this set up correctly to do. I do not have a database to connect to so i cannot test it out right now.
   <template>
      <v-carousel>
        <v-carousel-item
            src="https://cdn.vuetifyjs.com/images/cards/docks.jpg"
            cover
        ></v-carousel-item>
    
        <v-carousel-item
            src="https://cdn.vuetifyjs.com/images/cards/hotel.jpg"
            cover
        ></v-carousel-item>
      </v-carousel>
      <div class="matching">
        <h1>Welcome to the Matching Page</h1>
        <router-link @click = "edit()" class="button">Edit Profile</router-link>
      </div>
      <div class="infoBox">
        <p class ="img">{{user.profilePicture}}</p>
        <p class="boldText">{{user.displayName}}</p>
        <p>Full name: {{user.name}}</p>
        <p>Age: {{user.age}}</p>
        <p>Height: {{user.height}}</p>
        <p>Biography: {{user.biography}}</p>
        <p class="boldText">Dislikes</p>
        <p class="dislikes">{{user.dislikes}}</p>
      </div>
      <button class="button" onclick="nextUser">move to next</button>
    
    
    </template>
    
    
    
    
    <script>
    import { useRouter } from 'vue-router';
    import apiClient from '@/axiosConfig'; // Import the Axios configuration
    import { ref } from 'vue';
    
    export default {
      name: 'MatchingPage',
      data() {
        return {
          photo: '', // Replace with actual photo path or URL
          activeTab: 'personal',
          user: {
            email: '',
            address: '',
            phoneNumber: '',
            age: '',
            height: '',
            displayName: '',
            profilePicture: '',
            contact: '',
            biography: '',
            preferences: new Set(),
            dislikes: new Set()
          },
          selectedDislikes: [],
          selectedPreferences: []
    
        };
      },
      methods:{
        edit() {
          const router = useRouter();
    
          function goToEditProfile() {
            router.push('/edit-profile');
          }
    
          return {goToEditProfile};
        },
        setup(){
          const users = async () => {
            try{
              //actually figure out how to pull data from database later
              const response = await apiClient.get('/database');
              console.log('fetch data response:', response.data); // Logging response data
              // grabbing the token back from the server (which will be in local storage)
              const { token } = response.data;
              if (token) {
                localStorage.setItem('token', token); // Store the token
                apiClient.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = `Bearer ${token}`; // Set default header
                console.log('fecth successfully');
              } else {
                console.error('No token received from server');
                alert('Failed to sign up, no token received');
              }
            } catch (error) {
              console.error('Signup failed:', error.response ? error.response.data : error);
              alert(`Signup failed: ${error.response ? error.response.data.message : "Network or server error"}`);
            }
          };
          return {users};
        },
        nextUser() {
          let currentIndex = 0
          const users = setup()
      // Check if there are more users to iterate through
          if (currentIndex < users.length - 1) {
          currentIndex++;
          return users[currentIndex];
        } else {
        // If currentIndex is at the end, wrap around to the beginning
          currentIndex = 0;
          return users[currentIndex];
      }
    }
      },
      }
    </script>

Is there a better way to set up my frontend so tat it goes to the next user and displays said users information upon clicking the button?
thank you

setup function is not a property of methods, setup function in this case is not necessary, move users function into methods.
then const users = await users() in nextUser(), since there is an await keyword, nextUser function should be async too.
also there is the problem in users(), after get the response, it is weird to update request header token here, well, it is weird, but ok, the best way could be do this in axios request interceptor, anyway, the response.data should contains some property like data holds all users list, or where comes all the users data?
so maybe also a line of return response.data?.data || [], if there is a data property in response.data
finally, database is just a place where the data stores at, it doesn't matter where the data is, it could be requested from the server, or just a local mock data. so in users() if do this
const mockUserList = [
{
            email: '',
            address: '',
            phoneNumber: '',
            age: '18',
            height: '178',
            displayName: 'Flame Author',
            profilePicture: '',
            contact: '',
            biography: '',
            preferences: new Set(),
            dislikes: new Set()
          },
{
            email: '',
            address: '',
            phoneNumber: '',
            age: '36',
            height: '162',
            displayName: 'Sindy Clasue',
            profilePicture: '',
            contact: '',
            biography: '',
            preferences: new Set(),
            dislikes: new Set()
          }
]
return mockUserList

should be ready for test

I will try that out thank you so much
